# How to find out what's wrong with an HDF5 file

Tags: octave, hdf5

I have an hdf5 file which was generated by clavis.  When I try to open it in octave, I get the following error:

```
error: load: error while reading hdf5 item decision
HDF5-DIAG: Error detected in HDF5 (1.8.4-patch1) thread 2964195136:
  #000: ../../../src/H5Gdeprec.c line 777 in H5Giterate(): group iteration failed
    major: Symbol table
    minor: Iteration failed
  #001: ../../../src/H5G.c line 1532 in H5G_iterate(): error iterating over links
    major: Symbol table
    minor: Iteration failed
  #002: ../../../src/H5Gobj.c line 599 in H5G_obj_iterate(): can't iterate over symbol table
    major: Symbol table
    minor: Iteration failed
  #003: ../../../src/H5Gstab.c line 522 in H5G_stab_iterate(): iteration operator failed
    major: Symbol table
    minor: Can't move to next iterator location
  #004: ../../../src/H5B.c line 1302 in H5B_iterate(): B-tree iteration failed
    major: B-Tree node
    minor: Iteration failed
  #005: ../../../src/H5B.c line 1225 in H5B_iterate_helper(): iterator function failed
    major: B-Tree node
    minor: Unable to list node
  #006: ../../../src/H5Gnode.c line 1021 in H5G_node_iterate(): iteration operator failed
    major: Symbol table
    minor: Can't move to next iterator location
```

How can I find out what's wrong with my file?  Or is this a bug in hdf5?

It opens in HDFView, but it still prints out the same error nonetheless

Here's the file: http://www.wikiupload.com/JRGTR40KV2EVR3G

Comment: I quickly checked your file and it seems fine (using HDF5 version 1.8.11 and `h5stat`, `h5dump`…). It's likely a bug in the version you are using, you should try to update HDF5.

Comment: Works in HDF5 1.8.10 too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out this is a bug in Octave (or rather a call to a deprecated HDF5 function. I don't know what was going on with HDFView).  I created a bug report for it: http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?39491